# PyPy translate 64bit

Tags: python, binary, translate, pypy, rpython

I can't seem to find the answer to this question anywhere. I'd just like to know, does the PyPy `translate.py` script produce 64bit or 32bit binary files? Is there an option to choose between the two that I'm missing or can PyPy only produce 32bit binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPython currently produces binaries according to the “host-Pyhton”, that is, typically a 32 bit binary on a 32 bit system and a 64 bit binary on a 64 bit system

However, to work cross-bit you can do the following:

#### On Linux

If you have a 64 bit system

- just translate to get a 64 bit binary or
- you can try to translate within a 32 bit `chroot` environment [[1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_bundled_32-bit_system_in_Arch64),[2](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/356),[3](https://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/amd64/howtos/chroot.xml),[4](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot)] to produce a 32 bit one.

If you have a 32 bit system

- you can only produce 32 bit binaries.

#### On OS X

On OS X > 10.7, you typically have a 64 bit system so

- just translate to get a 64 bit binary or
- use the environment variable `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT` to control the “bitness” of python. For a 32 bit binary, you can run

  ```
  PYTHONPATH=$PYPYPATH:… VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes python $PYPYPATH/rpython/bin/rpython target….py
  ```

  Note that you *have to* use `python` in this case (typically, `rpython` detects an installed `pypy` and uses that), because `pypy` does not respect the versioner variable and does not come as a 32 bit binary for OS X in the first place.